# Is there an equivalent of cbind() or bind_cols() in sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparklyr

I'm trying the simple operation of binding two different dataframes (with the same row counts - and the rows match) in sparklyR.

For example:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local[*]")
iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris, name="iris", overwrite=TRUE)

#check column names
colnames(iris_tbl)

#subset iris into two df's
subdf <- iris_tbl %>%
  select(Sepal_Length,Sepal_Width) 

subdf1 <- iris_tbl %>%
  select(Petal_length,Petal_Width,Species)

#try to bind back together
dfCombine <- bind_cols(subdf,subdf1)
```

The error message I'm getting:

```
#Error
Error in cbind_all(x) : basic_string::resize
```

I've tried `combine()`, `cbind_all`, `cbind()`, and `c()`. None are working.

Comment: have you tried `union_all`? See https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/76

Comment: `union_all` is for binding two dataframes with the exact same columns (i.e., it is like `rbind` and is similar to `UNION` in SQL.

Comment: Oups, sorry. In that case it's not looking too good due to partitioning of data. Found a discussion about `bind_cols` here: https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/556

Answer (score 4):

It is too late so I hope that it will be good for others.

To bind two different dataframes (same as R cbind), we can use **sdf_bind_cols** ([Sparklyr Reference](https://spark.rstudio.com/reference/sdf_bind.html))

Code for the above problem:

```
sdf_bind_cols(subdf, subdf1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
sub2 <- sdf_bind_row(subdf, subdf1)
```

Comment: per the Sparklyr documentation, I think you should use `sdf_bind_rows` (row**s**)